# NLP: Arrange words with tags into proper English sentence?

Tags: nlp

lets say I have a sentence:

```
"you hello how are ?"
```

I get output of:

`you_PRP hello_VBP how_WRB are_VBP`

What is best way to arrange the wording into proper English sentence like: `Hello how are you ?`

I am new to this whole natural language processing so I am unfamiliar with many terms. 
The only way I can think of on top of my head is - Using statements to determine:
`adverb - verb - noun` and then re-arrange them based on that?

Note: Lets assume I am trying to form proper question, so ignore determining if it's a question or a statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into [language models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_model). A bigram language model, for example, will give you the probability of observing a sentence on the basis of the two-word sequences in that sentence. On the basis of a corpus of texts, it will have learned that "how are" has a higher probability of occurring than "are how". If you multiply the probabilities of all these two-word sequences in a sentence, you will get the probability of the sentence.

In other words, this is how you can solve your problem:

1. Find a corpus (either a simple text corpus, or a corpus that has been tagged with part-of-speech tags).
2. Learn a language model from that corpus. You can do this simply on the basis of the words, or on the basis of the words and their part-of-speech tags, as in your example.
3. Generate all possible sequences of your target words.
4. Use the language model to compute the probabilities of all those sequences.
5. Pick the sequence with the highest probability.

If you work with Python, nltk has an [api for training and using language models](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.model.html). Otherwise, [KenLM](https://kheafield.com/code/kenlm/) is a popular language modelling package.